# how to use stylish userscript or javascript to remove this html element?

Tags: javascript, html, userscripts

on a website i visit, i want to remove an ad-link from the page by writing script. how would i remove the `<a href-"ad">ad</a>` page element? I guess the best way would be using javascript, and using a tampermonkey chrome extension to run the script. otherwise, using stylish and a css script.

```
<div class=main>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class=stuff>
    //bunch of other stuff
    </div>
    <a href="ad.com">ad</a>

</div>
```

Comment: while you can run something from the console and remove elements manually you're probably better off running something like adblock.

Comment: Stylish is a _userstyle_ manager. You basically tell it "when the URL is `www.example.com/.*`, apply `a[href='ad.com']{display:none}` as a CSS style".

Comment: Also consider using AdBlock+

Comment: You may want to use `#main>a { display: none; }`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have made a chrome extension for this purpose, named **Js-Injector**. It is available from github on https://github.com/shahverdy/JS-Injector. Unfortunately I can not deploy it on Chrome Web Store, because of US sanctions on my country. There are some samples in extension for this purpose, you can easily work with it.

In **Js-Injector** you can add the following code for your website:

```
$(function(){
    $("a[href='ad.com']").remove();
})
```

**EDIT**: There are some other extensions like Tampermonkey available. But there are some important issues that should be considered at the time of choosing proper extension:

- Js-Injector is really easy to use
- Js-Injector has Import/Export feature available for your scripts.
- There are some predefined samples, so you can select to use them without writing any codes.
- Js-Injector is really light.
- Js-Injector runs scripts for each website on its own scope, so it doesn't consume that much RAM/CPU

Comment: How does it differ from a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)?

Comment: It is something simpler and lighter, plus have import export feature for manual scripts.

Comment: I can copy/paste to TM too :-)

Comment: What if you have tens of scripts?

Comment: Consider merging them into one

Comment: Using TM this way, it will cost a lot of memory and CPU.

Comment: I suggest adding this discussion (pros and cons vs. tampermonkey and other options) to the answer

Comment: Just edited my answer, see if it is OK now